# Nodejs Create csv file in azure function and email the file as an attachment

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, email, azure-functions

I have a requirement to create a csv file in azure function using nodejs and send the csv file as an attachment to configured users.

Azure function will first get the data from mysql database and then create csv file and email the file as attachment. Any suggestions on how this can be done ? I can get the data from mysql but unclear about the process after that.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you want to send an email with csv file, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327705/node-js-nodemailer-array-of-objects-to-csv-file-as-attachment-in-email

Comment: @sanjay    Do you have any update?